# Regular expression to match 3 Characters with comma seperation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I want my regular expression to validate set of characters in such a way like..

```
  ABC,DEF,GHI....
```

3set of characters NOT allowing Numbers with separation of Comma,

Can any one please help.

Answer (score 1):

my tip would be to use following code:

```
string toBeTested = ...
Match m = Regex.Match(toBeTested, "^[a-zA-Z]{3}(\\,[a-zA-Z]{3})*$");
```

`a-zA-Z` matches a letter

`{3}` exactly three times

and then a group of comma (escaped) followed by three letters (`*` == zero or more times)

`^` means beginning of a string
`$` means the end of a string

which means your **whole** string should be validated

Comment: it also matches strings like "ABC" - if you want at least one comma to be in it, replace `*` with a `+`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
(\S{3},)+(\S{3})$
```

Comment: here i want character restriction too

Comment: What characters restriction do you want?

Comment: this one also matches strings consisting of letters of length 3*k

Comment: @woj2ch yeah, I was wrong with '?' sign. Thanks for pointing this to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's regularexpression matching anything between A-Z

```
var resultString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(subjectString, "[a-zA-Z]{3},").Value;
```

Comment: As yours is still giving problem i tryed ^([a-z]{3}+)(,\s*[a-z]{3}+)*$  still i cant get my result can you please help, i cant restrict chars

Comment: What you mean restricting characters? You want some specific characters? or do you want it to skip if there's numbers?

Answer (score 0):

"([a-zA-Z]{3},)+"
I think comma shouldnt be escaped, otherwise it would be like \,

Comment: well [a-zA-Z] goes for Latin symbols upper and lower-case. {3} says that there should be exactly 3 of them and comma goes for comma :) () group entire expression and + sign tells that ith should appear once or more times in string

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
    string s = "ABC,DEF,GHI";

    Match match = Regex.Match(s, "^([a-zA-Z]{3},)+[a-zA-Z]{3}$");

    if (match.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine("String passes");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("String fails");
    }
```